# Word for 'controlled by', with reference to an external controller

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for 'controlled by' applicable in " My body was controlled by the mind "

Comment: Why did you use the definite article with "mind"? What is "*the* mind"? Whose mind is it?

Comment: _Control_ demands that there be one entity controlling another entity. The controller must be separate, and thus external. Though, as your example shows, they may be under the same roof.

Comment: By definition, with an active verb the subject acts on the object, and not the other way around.  Any object being controlled is (relatively) passive compared to the controlling subject.  If you want to invert this relationship you cannot use a standard subject/verb/object form, but must do some sort linguistic gymnastics involving "by", "through", "using", etc.  Otherwise you must ascribe some degree of volition to your object-turned-subject using a verb such as "obeys".

Comment: Yes, there is a word for "controlled". And that word is "controlled". Best of all, it is the only word for "controlled". No other word means "controlled".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the most normal expression to use for this would be **controlled by**.

An alternative expression that you could use is **Possessed** - this term had its origin in the Bible where certain individuals in the New Testament were 'possessed by unclean spirits' or 'possessed by demons'. I think I am safe in saying that the interpretation of this part of these parts of the Bible turns out to be a controvesial issue, but the term itself 'Possession' or 'Possessed' is reasonably well known. A.S. Byatt had a popular book out called 'Possession' some time ago.

In this context you could use possession or possessed but the normal sense of this is possession by something from outside the body being possessed - so it would be strange to say 'he was possessed by his mind' - though you could say 'he was possessed by the desire to eat chocolate...' or something similar.

Comment: You may replace "controlled by" by "**under the control of**". An alternative would be "*supervised*", but it does'nt seem appropriate, because body and mind belong to the same person.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reorder the expression "the mind controls the body" so that you have "the body [??] the mind", try *follows* or *obeys*.

> [Follow](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/follow):
> 4. to conform to, comply with, or act in accordance with; obey
>
> [Obey](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obey):
> 3. (of things) to respond conformably in action to

If you wish to retain the word *was*, you can use the form "was following/obeying".